# OpenCV: Enumerate shapes in binary image?

Tags: opencv

If I've got an image which look, for example, like this:

```
0101001
1101101
0101001
```

Is there any method I can use which will find both of those disconnected blobs? For example, producing something like this:

```
0102003
1102203
0102003
```

Like [scipy.ndimage.label](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html#scipy.ndimage.measurements.label).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is blob library. There was [cvblobslib](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib), it seems outdated. Try [cvBlob](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/) — looks great.

Also, there is related function in OpenCV [`cvFloodFill`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#floodfill), though you'll have to write code to find and manage connected components.